# Tests won't run: "The executable for the test bundle at '../DerivedData/../*.xctest' could not be found"

Tags: unit-testing, ios7, xcode5, cocoapods

I have a Xcode 5.1 project (projA) which included a private framework (frameworkB) via Cocoapods. Everything was working, building and testing and even the weather was nice. But, because the frameworkB is being developed in parallel with the projA, I decided to include the project of the frameworkB (proj B) in projA, again via Cocoapods but as a reference with :path ='path/to/projB'

In the result the projB compiles and builds and runs on device, the tests target also compiles and builds but doesn't run, the simulator start and this message is displayed:

```
2014-04-14 11:08:34.990 xctest[98973:303] The executable for the test bundle at
/Users/myNameHere/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projB-manyLettersHere/Build
/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/projB.xctest could not be found.
Program ended with exit code: 1
```

Also the weather is not so nice anymore.

Google didn't help. Other stackoverflow question are more about transition from Sentest cu XCTest.

Any hint that will put me on the right path will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause and solution to this problem is (as usual) very simple:

The framework that was being built contained a bundle, which was required, but (of course) was not generated by the Pod project, even if in the podspec i  specified the *spec.resources* pram. The solution was to create a *spec.resource_bundle* with the required name and resource files.

Why it would throw this error and not a compile-time or runtime error i still don't know :|
(the *projB.xctest* was present at the path in error)